# How to get order output after using group in the sql query?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, cakephp

I have a my sql table with customer names and orders that they placed over time.

table column names are id, customer name, order value, status, and created and modified.

I am able to group customer names and number of orders.

using a sql query like this..

```
SELECT Customer,count(OrderPrice) FROM Orders GROUP BY Customer
```

It works fine. But I want the output to be ordered by number of orders(count). Customer with lots of orders comes at the top of the list.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
    SELECT Customer
         , count(OrderPrice) cnt
      FROM Orders
  GROUP BY Customer
  ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: FYI: The number in the ORDER BY is called an "ordinal" - it refers to the column value in the 2nd position of the SELECT clause in this example.  Not a recommended practice - if the column order changes, the ordering will still be based on whatever the second column is.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - Fair enough, I fixed it :).

Answer (score 1):

SELECT Customer,
           count(OrderPrice) order_count 
    FROM Orders 
    GROUP BY Customer
    ORDER BY order_count desc

Enjoy!

Comment: Your GROUP BY / ORDER BY are backwards (i.e. GROUP BY comes before ORDER BY).